# GoogleMaps v3 - map doesn't want to load markers from mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, markers

I have problems with maps showing markers from a MySql database.

Map doesn't show, but I can see the map starts to initialize. It doesn't show any markers on it.

I am using the same map, showing only one `lat/long` from a mysql db. It is working perfectly fine without markers, but when I loop to place markersit just doesn't want to show markers.

I really don't want to complicate things with xml tables. I was also using similar code in v2 maps and everything was working fine. This is my code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
        (function (){

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
```

php starts

```
        while($apa = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $lat_map = $apa["lat"];
            $lon_map = $apa["lon"]; 
            $adr_apa = $apa["adresa"];
```

php ends

```
            var options = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_map; ?>, <?php echo $lon_map; ?>),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_map; ?>, <?php echo $lon_map; ?>),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Click Me'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: '<p><?php echo $adr_apa; ?></p>'
                        });
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

  <?php } ?>    

        })();

        });

    </script>


<?php   

echo '

<body>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 420px"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: What does the code the browser sees look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  It looks to me like you should be getting a javascript error `options` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring marker and options javascript variables as many times as elements you have :)
It's not about google maps, its about your JS is not correct and the browser doesn't interpret it.
Move the variable declaration outside the while

```
   var marker, options;

   <? php stuff ?>
```